# A quantity associated to a foliated manifold and its non-commutative interpretation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, noncommutative-geometry, foliations, groupoids

Let $M$ be a compact $n$-dimensional manifold. Assume that $F$ is a $k$-dimensional foliation of $M$.
The graph $G(M,F)$ of this foliation is a $(n+k)$-dimensional manifold. We recall its definition:
The graph $G(M,F)$ is the equivalence class of all $[x,y,\alpha]$ where $x,y$ lie on the same leaf and $\alpha$ is a path in the same leaf joining $x$ to $y$. The equivalence relation is $[x,y,\alpha]\sim [x,y,\beta]$ iff $\alpha$, $\beta$ induce the same holonomy with respect to chosen transversal sections.

So there are obvious embedding of $M$ and also embedding of each (compact) leaf into the graph of the foliation. The embedding has this formulation:  each $x$ is mapped to $[x,x, \alpha_x]$ where $\alpha_x$ is the constant curve.

> To every foliation $F$ of a compact manifold $M$ we associate a quantity as follows:
> $q(M,F)$ is the supremum of intersection numbers $\# (M,L)$ where $L$ varies in all compact leaves of $F$ and $M$ and $L$ are considered as submanifolds of $G(M,F)$.

**First question:** What is the non-commutative interpretation of this quantity in terms of $C^*$-algebraic frameworks (according to $C^*$ algebra associated to a foliated manifold)?

**Second question:** What is this quantity for the Reeb foliation$\mathcal{R}$ of $S^3$? In the other word: what is the intersection number of the unique compact leaf of $\mathcal{R}$ with $S^3$, where both site in the corresponding groupoid foliation $G(S^3,\mathcal{R}$)?

**Remark:** The intersection number discussed in this question is computed after an appropriate perturbation of underlying manifolds $M$ and $L$, as submanifolds of $G(M,F), such that they would intersect each other transversally.(See the book of Hirsch Differential topology,  chapter of transversality)

Comment: @YCor I appreciate you edit to my question.