# Can topological invariants be built from something different than integrals of differential forms?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, chern-classes

I don't know whether the question is very stupid or less so, so I will give a little context, but it probably will stay too vague nonetheless.

### Prelude

It is known that some topological invariants admit a representation as certain integrals.

To name a few examples, the fact that Euler characteristics $\chi(M)$ of a manifold $M$ without a boundary equals an integral of curvature form
$$\chi(M)  = \int_M \Omega$$
is the statement of Gauss-Bonnet-Chern theorem, and the fact that the integral of $i$-th power of the curvature form is proportional to $(2\pi)^i$ times some integer $$\int \wedge^iF = (2\pi)^i k_i$$
is the statement of Chern-Weil theory. In the more general setting all these examples fall under the common theme of index theory.

Many of these invariants, actually, can also be obtained from certain physical theories, such as Einstein (which describes metric tensor), Yang-Mills (which describes 1-forms taking values in matrices) theories or their various generalizations. For example, the second Chern number says how many instantons are present in Yang-Mills theory, while the first Chern number is responsible for quantum Hall effect.

Moreover, physics can provides us with some other topological invariants, for instance certain links and knots invariants, which are the Wilson loop averages $P_\gamma = \int DA^\mu \mathrm {Tr} ({\mathcal {P}}\exp i\oint _{\gamma}A_{\mu }dx^{\mu }) $ in various Chern-Simons theories. Here $A_\mu$ is a connection, and other symbols aren't really relevant.

### The question

There has recently been a resurgence of interest in the theories based on something different than differential forms, i.e. theories of antisymmetric tensors. These theories, the simplest example of which probably is $$S = \int \left(\frac{1}{2}\partial_t u_i \partial_t u^i - \frac{1}{2}C^{ijkl}(\partial_i u_j+\partial_j u_i)(\partial_k u_l+\partial_l u_k)\right) d^4 x $$ don't seem to admit a nice description in term of differential forms like Yang-Mills theory $S = \int F \star \wedge F$ with $F = d A + [A,A]$ (note the symmetric combination instead of usual antisymmetric in Yang-Mills theory).

Hence is my question: do there exist any topological invariants whose corresponding integral representations are built from something different than differential forms?

**Update:**
One can see what physicists write on this matter using the following arXiv papers as a starting reference: [Pretko/Radzihovsky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.11044.pdf) and [Seiberg/Shao](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10466.pdf). However, these theories are indeed exotic in the sense that they (coming from theories on a lattice) are, actually, formulated on $\mathbb{R}^{n,1}$ and
not on general manifold. In the Pretko paper, for example, $C^{ijkl}$ is a matrix of some coefficients. In order to put this action on a more or less general manifold one would have at least to say that $C^{ijkl}$ transforms as a certain density, but that is just my guess. Basically, I don't know what to say about a general manifold.

As for my belief in some topological invariants behinds this story, it comes from the existence of peculiar (for example, not being able to freely move in every direction) excitations, called fractons.

Comment: For good enough spaces $X$, the data is equivalent to its cochain complexes $C^\cdot(X)$. By passing to cohomologies you get invariants from integrations that are easier-to-compute but do not capture the same amount of information. So $C^\cdot(X)$ is one of a topological invariant that's not from differential forms. Another choice is $\Pi_\cdot(X)$.

Comment: How certain are you that the integrands in these theories are not secretly coordinate expressions of some differential form, possibly with values in some Lie algebra?  I don't think the Yang-Mills equations were originally expressed in this language.  Part of the reason I ask is that differential forms are precisely the objects whose integrals are well-defined independent of a coordinate system (this is more or less a theorem), so I'm left wondering if these new theories are explicitly tied to some coordinate system.

Comment: Is there a reference for the example you give? Like @PaulSiegel, I'm not convinced that this can't be written in terms of differential forms and geometric operators such as the Hodge star. In fact, if this functional is coordinate independent, there has to be a way to do so for the reasons cited by Paul.

Comment: @PaulSiegel I'm not sure of anything, but I have been thinking (and looking for some literature) about these matters for quite some time already. The only way that I could write this action in terms of forms was to use the language of [bi-forms][https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0208155v2.pdf]. But it didn't lead to the general $C^{ijkl}$, and, moreover, puts some of these coefficients equal to zero. I added update concerning explicit coordinates.

Comment: @DeaneYang I added some references and my thoughts about the concerns that you made explicit. However, I just want to add that this theory may not be formulated on general manifold in a simple way for a reason similar to why you cannot easily have a spin structure, and hence a theory with fermions, on a general manifold.

Comment: @user108687, I can see I'm in over my head here. But I'm curious. Could you explain briefly how you know or why you believe these are topological invariants?

Comment: @DeaneYang I have only a belief, which is based on the following physical reasoning. Differential equations, originating in physics usually have two kinds of solutions. One of them describes small perturbations of a certain ``trivial solution'' (photons/phonons/...). The other describes different nontrivial solutions and is usually connected with nontrivial topology (vortices, instantons, monopoles, domain walls, etc.). Now, in these fracton theories people found new (actually, old, but missed) kinds of solutions of second kind. I suspect that there must be some mathematics behind them.

Comment: For a compact  orientable manifold  M of dimension $n$  is this quantity an invariant(independent of chosen foliation) and is it a  a topological one?:for a codimension one foliation $F$ of M with a finite number of compact leaves, define $q(M,F)=\sum_L \#(L,M)$ the sum of intersection number of compact leaves with M in the groupoid foliation?If $\sum$ does not work what about the "supremum". Here is description of this quantity https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376572/a-quantity-associated-to-a-foliated-manifold-and-its-non-commutative-interpretat

Comment: @AliTaghavi I don't know anything about this invariant, but I will surely look into it, thank you!

Comment: You are well come!  BTW do you think that two other tags "characteristic  classes"  and "index theory" would be appropriate for your question? I am not sure it is  just a  suggestion and question.

Comment: @user108687, sounds pretty cool and convincing.

Comment: I see integration like a trace, that is ultimately, as a "duality". Thus, it seems to me that everything depends on the tensor of "dualization", I mean, the "metric" and the spaces in duality.